# Scene's to open inside the ContianerView through UIButtons

Tags: uistoryboardsegue, container-view

iOS6 XCode 4.5.2

I have a MainViewController which has 5 UIButtons on the left (B1 - B5).  In the middle of the Main View Controller, I have a ContainerView.  This ContainerView has 5 scenes (the initial scene is also a navigation controller) that I would like to wire up to the 5 UIButtons.  When buttons are pressed, I'd like the scenes to open to up inside the container.

Currently when the app runs, I can click the Next button on the initial ContainerView Scene and step through all 5 scenes. I can even come back to the first scene by pressing the Back button step-by-step.  However, after wiring up the UIButtons, through the Storyboard, when I click on any the buttons, instead of opening up the scene inside the container, they open up in Full Screen, stacking on top of the MainViewContoller.

When a button is pressed, how can I get the scenes (Scene 1, Scene 2, etc.) to open up inside the container?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you programming for the iPhone? The iOS Human Interface Guidelines specify that "[on iPhone, a navigation bar always displays across the full width of the screen.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41)". In this case, I suggest you get rid of the second navigation controller.

Comment: Yes, it is for an iPhone.  good point!  Thank you!  Ill have to use buttons to go back and forth instead? Will apply reject it if I submit it in its current state? 

Any recommandation on how to get the views to work like the navigation controller?

Comment: @user1107173 Apple will generally reject an app that doesn't adhere to their guidelines. What I was trying to say is that you should use only one level of navigation at all times on the iPhone. Maybe you could remove your top-level navigation controller, factor your buttons out into a tab bar controller in which you could then nest your current second-level navigation controller? Like in the [HIG, figure 1-4](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10).

Comment: @user1107173 did I answer your question btw?